# What does InetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress() actually mean?

Tags: java, network-programming, inet

Here is some code to determine the local host name that is supposed to work on a multi-homed box:

```
 /**
 * Work out the first local host name by iterating the network interfaces
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws SocketException
 */
private String findFirstLocalHostName() throws SocketException {

    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ifaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (ifaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface iface = ifaces.nextElement();
        Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
        while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress add = addresses.nextElement();
            if (!add.isLoopbackAddress() && add.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                return add.getHostName();
            }
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to determine local hostname");
}
```

Does the call to isSiteLocalAddress introduce a bug? I can't find any useful information about this method, but I have a feeling that it relates to IP v 6 only and is deprecated.

Comment: For clarity, I didn't mean that the method was deprecated... just the notion of "site local" address in IPv6 as per http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3879.txt

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The method is [definitely not deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html#isSiteLocalAddress%28%29) and it's definitely not just used in IPv6.

In IPv4 there are [3 network address ranges that are defined for site-local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses): 10/8, 172.16/12 and 192.168/16.

Reading `Inet4Address.isSiteLocalAddress()` shows that addresses from exactly those 3 networks will return `true` on those methods.

IPv6 has a similar concept, here these addresses are called [unique local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address).

Effectively this tells you if the address you have is definitely not a public one (note that even if this method returns `false`, the address might still not be public).

Comment: see [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=NyxObrhTv5oC&lpg=PT187&dq=InetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()&pg=PT186#v=onepage&q&f=false). it returns true if the address is an IPv6 site-local address.

Comment: @John: yes, I know that there is a similar meaning in IPv6 as well, but I don't know the specifics of it. But since the question implied that it's IPv6-only, I wanted to clarify that aspect. (By the way, I can't read the page you linked to).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation...

For an `Inet4Address`, it checks to see if it's one of the RFC1918 "unrouteable" addresses: 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16.

For an `Inet6Address`, it checks the first two octets to see if it's a real "site local" address.

Answer (score 0):

'Site local' is a deprecated name for private IP space. (Some nuances, but basically right.) See RFC 1918.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across what I believe is a similar problem: *trying to determine what IPv6 I should use for LAN comuncation*:

- IMHO, `Inet6Address.isSiteLocalAddress()` is useless. Given that the `0xFEC0` prefix has been depricated by [RFC 3879](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3879.txt) as @tigz mentioned. I have yet to see any device (android, win, osx) actually have a `0xFEC0` (with limited testing)

  `//from java.net.Inet6Address (1.8.0_45)
      boolean isSiteLocalAddress() {
          return ((ipaddress[0] & 0xff) == 0xfe
                 && (ipaddress[1] & 0xc0) == 0xc0);
      }`
- `0xFE80` address although not supposed be used for traffic (from my understanding and reading ([www.cisco.com](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-version-6-ipv6/113328-ipv6-lla.html))) did work for LAN communication with my single router (ping6, curl, http).
- My Global Unicast (which is just another name for public IP) [`2601::/20`](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET6-2601-1.html) from Comcast worked for my LAN communication. So I would say that this is the correct address to use.

Prefix table: [www.iana.org](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the isSiteLocalAddress method is not deprecated.

**isSiteLocalAddress - Explanation**

*indicating if the InetAddress is a site local address; or false if address is not a site local unicast address.*

The InetAddress even have two direct subclasses;

[Inet4Address](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html) and 
[Inet6Address](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html)

The best bet is to read the JavaDocs.

Which version of the JDK are you using?